# "Error: out of gas" error appears for some prices

Tags: 0x

I have deployed a local instance of 0X API with the environment variables:

```
CHAIN_ID=250
ETHEREUM_RPC_URL=https://rpc.ftm.tools
```

When trying to get the prices it sometimes works well for some prices but there are pairs that throw an internal server error. When checking the details I saw it shows the error:

```
"Error: out of gas\n    at SwapHandlers._getSwapQuoteAsync
```

For example this price request is failing:

```
http://127.0.0.1:3000/swap/v1/price?sellToken=WFTM&buyToken=USDC&sellAmount=10000000000000000000
```

Can you guys help me to identify what could be causing the internal server error?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a better RPC endpoint which has a higher eth call gas limit. The public one you're using is very small.

When creating routes a lot of gas is used in reading the chain.

Comment: Thank you so much @Jacob, do I need to mount my own nodes? or do you know some highly available RPC?

Comment: [Quicknode](https://www.quicknode.com/) supports Fantom, or you can run your own nodes. We actually have a fix that may release soon which will lower the gas on Fantom.

It occurs on small amounts (where there are MANY pools with liquidity) and goes away on larger amounts. So if you try a larger amount of FTM sell you should see success.

Comment: Thank you I have confirmed what you said, I got the price for a higher amount of FTM (100 fmts) against USDC and this time it passed. I'll take a look at Quicknode.